# Flutter 1.22.0 IOS app connection lost issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I have migrated to **Flutter 1.22.0** from the older version. When I am trying to run the application in the IOS Simulator, it just opens the app and crashes and says connection lost. However in the Android Studio, it still shows it is running, I mean the Run & Debug button is disabled but the stop button is active.

The **flutter run --verbose** output is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GAVSizL2LCE7ic__lYcx_Z59DHaVYAGO/view?usp=sharing).

Following logs I am seeing at the end after that nothing happens.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           18.4s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.1.1
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60600000 started
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
Waiting for iPhone 11 Pro to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55184/qe2GMcl6YA3=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro...
Lost connection to device.
```

Whenever I start the IOS simulator, it gives me the "**Spotlight quit unexpectedly.**" error. See the below screenshot. Not sure whether it is related to this issue or not...
[image]

Comment: Can you share `flutter run --verbose` result?

Comment: Thank, I have added the link to the output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are still using an older version of Flutter. v1.22.2 is released this week. Try to upgrade Flutter with `flutter upgrade --force`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated to the latest one but it is still giving same error.